# Make file e compilação no terminal

Tags: c, compilação, makefile, make

[image: Imagem]

Preciso que o meu makefile seja executado no terminal de forma que não seja necessário no terminal inserir `$ time make run`, e sim apenas `make run`, e que ele mostre o tempo de execução da mesma forma. Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Codigo do Make:

```
NAME=TP1_main2
CC=gcc
TODOS_ARQUIVOS_PONTOH = TP1_main2.c 
TODOS_ARQUIVOS_OBJ = $(NAME).o TP1_main2.o

%.o: %.c $(TODOS_ARQUIVOS_PONTOH)
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(OPCOES_COMPILADOR)

all: $(TODOS_ARQUIVOS_OBJ)
    gcc -o $(NAME) $^ $(OPCOES_COMPILADOR)

run: all
    ./$(NAME)

clean:
    rm *.o $(NAME)
```

Comment: Qual tempo você quer registrar? Da compilação ou só do rodar?

Comment: Aproveitando, fica melhor se você postar o código do Makefile, fica melhor para copiar e colar na resposta

Comment: Quero registrar o tempo de todo o processo. E obrigado pela dica sobre o make, das próximas vezes irei fazer dessa maneira.

Comment: Infelizmente, a diretiva `time` registra o tempo de um comando passado. Se você quer todo o `make`, o correto é fazer exatamente isso. Até é possível fazer uma chamada recursiva a `make` e por o `time` ali, mas isso é aparentemente gambiótico

Comment: É sempre uma boa diretiva colocar o código da dúvida aqui no SO-pt

Comment: Obrigado, já ajudou bastante.